# ¿Cómo llenar una tabla desde net core api en blazor de 2 modelos?

Tags: c#, .net-core, blazor

Tengo una tabla tipo contrato que la lleno con un foreach usando un async task

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var v in tp)
{
    
    <tr>
        <td>@v.Id</td>
        <td>@v.Tipo</td>
        <td>@v.Tamano</td>
        <td>@v.NumProyectos</td>
        <td>@v.idgiro</td>
        <td>@v.TipoContratacion</td>
        <td>@v.Servicio</td>
        <td>@v.Porcentaje</td> 
    </tr>
}
```

```
@code{
 protected async Task Cargartaba()
 {
     tp = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<CotizacionTipoProyecto>>("api/CotizacionTipoProyecto");
 }
}
```

pero quiero que el **idgiro** se muestre la descripción del modelo Giro, y no se vea el id, es posible meter un proceso en el foreach? o hay otra manera de hacerlo?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo resolvi, cree un task que se traiga la lista de el tipo de giro (tambien la uso para llenar un dropdownlist)

```
 protected async Task Cddlgiro()
 {   
   gr=  await  Http.GetFromJsonAsync <List<Giro>> 
  ("api/CotizacionTipoProyecto/Giro");
 }
```

y la llamo a iniciar la pagina

```
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
 await Cargartaba(); //cargo la tabla
 await Cddlgiro(); //cargo la lista de tipos de giro
 }
```

y al final mi tabla queda asi:

```
<tbody>
@foreach (var v in tp)
{                          
    <tr>
        <td>@v.Id</td>
        <td>@v.Tipo</td>
        <td>@v.Tamano</td>
        <td>@v.NumProyectos</td>
        <td>@gr.Find(g=> g.Id == v.Giro).DescripcionGiro </td>
        <td>@v.TipoContratacion</td>
        <td>@v.Servicio</td>
        <td>@v.Porcentaje</td> 
    </tr>
}
 </tbody>
```

y mi controlador conectado a EF net core api, lo llamo asi al proceso de carga de lista:

```
  //GET: Listado de tabla giros
   [HttpGet("Giro")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Giro>>> getgiros()
    {
    return await _context.Giros.ToListAsync();
    }
```

Comment: En lugar de tener dos llamadas a BD y 2 http request, devuelve todo en un único endpoint y luego simplemente muestra los valores del DTO que sería un modelo que contiene la información de ambas **tablas**

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz como puedo hacer un endpoint para todos los controladores de api net core?

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, me refería a que en un único endpoint devuelvas un modelo con toda la información requerida.